# Повтор картинок в Swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, spritekit

У меня есть спрайт SKSpriteNode размера, например, 200x200px. 
Как мне сделать, чтобы я задал ему картинку 50x50px и она не расширилась до размера спрайта, а просто повторялась до тех пор, пока не заполнит спрайт?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: поставить 4 одинаковых спрайта 2х2

Comment: Есть какой-нибудь другой способ? (к тому же я заранее не знаю размер спрайта)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого лучше использовать SKTileMapNode

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var tileNode : SKTileMapNode!

    var mapSize: (row: Int, col: Int) = (1, 1) {
        didSet {
            guard oldValue != self.mapSize else {return}

            self.tileNode.numberOfRows = mapSize.row
            self.tileNode.numberOfColumns = mapSize.col

            let group = self.tileNode.tileGroup(atColumn: 0, row: 0)!
            self.tileNode.fill(with: group)
        }
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.tileNode = self.childNode(withName: "//Rock") as! SKTileMapNode
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        let size = self.view!.bounds.size
        let row  = Int(ceil(size.height / self.tileNode.tileSize.height))
        let col  = Int(ceil(size.width / self.tileNode.tileSize.width))
        self.mapSize = (row, col)
    }
}
```

self.tileNode - это наш слой карты. А в методе update мы просто дорисовываем ячейки